# How can I get my website to load?

Tags: web, browser-cache

I have built a few webpages on my laptop using the Homestead web based site editor. The sites load fine on all devices in my house except for my laptop. Almost every time the pages time out before they load. It does not load even partially. Initially when this started I could clear cache/cookies and it would then load. Now I can't get them to load at all in chrome, ff or ie. They load fine on my ipad and other pcs in the house.

Answer (score 0):

It is issue of your laptop you just clear your temp files and try to another from data card.you can send me URL of your site.

Comment: www.ochomeinspect.com

Comment: I deleted all temp files and still cannot load page.

Comment: is it public URL if send me ,and attach your screen shot of laptop.

Comment: Yes. Chrome says "This webpage is not available".

Comment: Can you send me URL ?